# R and DPLYR: I'm trying to summarize an average site score for a nonnumeric variable and I can't get it to convert to a percentage

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I am analyzing a dataset of physical habitat characteristics of a river. For each site we have a variety of variables that were measured across a 10 point transect. Summarizing most of these variables by Location, Reach, and Transect is simple but one of them, substrate, is scored using nonnumeric data. I am trying to create a summary for each transect to use in my statistical analysis but using `dplyr`'s `summarize` and `pivot_wider` does not work. When I use `summarize` the nonnummeric value for the substrate variable returns an error, and for `pivot_wider` I do not have a value to enter for the new columns created from the Substrate variable.

This is an example of the raw data I am trying to summarize.

| Location | Reach | Transect | Flow | Depth | Substrate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RIX | 1 | 1 | 0.4 | 14 | CO |
| RIX | 1 | 1 | 0.5 | 12 | BO |
| RIX | 1 | 1 | 0.3 | 11 | SA |
| RIX | 1 | 1 | 0.4 | 14 | GR |
| RIX | 1 | 1 | 0.4 | 14 | CO |
| RIX | 1 | 2 | 0.4 | 17 | CO |
| RIX | 1 | 2 | 0.5 | 18 | SA |
| RIX | 1 | 2 | 0.1 | 22 | SA |
| RIX | 1 | 2 | 0.6 | 15 | GR |
| RIX | 1 | 2 | 0.4 | 14 | SILT |
| RIX | 2 | 1 | 0.4 | 14 | CO |
| RIX | 2 | 1 | 0.5 | 12 | BO |
| RIX | 2 | 1 | 0.3 | 11 | SA |
| RIX | 2 | 1 | 0.4 | 14 | GR |
| RIX | 2 | 1 | 0.4 | 14 | CO |
| RIX | 2 | 2 | 0.4 | 17 | CO |
| RIX | 2 | 2 | 0.5 | 18 | SA |
| RIX | 2 | 2 | 0.1 | 22 | SA |
| RIX | 2 | 2 | 0.6 | 15 | GR |
| RIX | 2 | 2 | 0.4 | 14 | SILT |
| ARA | 1 | 1 | 0.4 | 14 | CO |
| ARA | 1 | 1 | 0.5 | 12 | BO |
| ARA | 1 | 1 | 0.3 | 11 | SA |
| ARA | 1 | 1 | 0.4 | 14 | GR |
| ARA | 1 | 1 | 0.4 | 14 | CO |
| ARA | 1 | 2 | 0.4 | 17 | CO |
| ARA | 1 | 2 | 0.5 | 18 | SA |
| ARA | 1 | 2 | 0.1 | 22 | SA |
| ARA | 1 | 2 | 0.6 | 15 | GR |
| ARA | 1 | 2 | 0.4 | 14 | SILT |
| ARA | 2 | 1 | 0.4 | 14 | CO |
| ARA | 2 | 1 | 0.5 | 12 | BO |
| ARA | 2 | 1 | 0.3 | 11 | SA |
| ARA | 2 | 1 | 0.4 | 14 | GR |
| ARA | 2 | 1 | 0.4 | 14 | CO |
| ARA | 2 | 2 | 0.4 | 17 | CO |
| ARA | 2 | 2 | 0.5 | 18 | SA |
| ARA | 2 | 2 | 0.1 | 22 | SA |
| RIX | 2 | 2 | 0.6 | 15 | GR |
| RIX | 2 | 2 | 0.4 | 14 | SILT |

Here is what I am trying to create.

| Location | Reach | Transect | Flow | Depth | CO | GR | SA | SILT | BO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RIX | 1 | 1 | 0.4 | 13 | .40 | .20 | .20 | 0 | .20 |
| RIX | 1 | 2 | 0.4 | 17.2 | .20 | .20 | .40 | .20 | 0 |
| RIX | 2 | 1 | 0.4 | 13 | .40 | .20 | .20 | 0 | .20 |
| RIX | 2 | 2 | 0.4 | 17.2 | .20 | .20 | .40 | .20 | 0 |

I am unsure how to go about filling the new columns I have created by using the `pivot_wider` function in `dplyr` and to keep the Transects separated by Location and Reach when I use the `summarize` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to add an id column (to make pivot_wider work) and a new column of ones (which serves as an indicator and as the value column when converting to wide format):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number(), value = 1) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "Substrate", values_from = "value", values_fill = 0) %>% 
  group_by(Location, Reach, Transect) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), mean), .groups = "drop") %>% 
  select(-id)
#> # A tibble: 8 × 10
#>   Location Reach Transect  Flow Depth    CO    BO    SA    GR  SILT
#>   <chr>    <int>    <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 ARA          1        1 0.4    13   0.4     0.2 0.2   0.2   0    
#> 2 ARA          1        2 0.4    17.2 0.2     0   0.4   0.2   0.2  
#> 3 ARA          2        1 0.4    13   0.4     0.2 0.2   0.2   0    
#> 4 ARA          2        2 0.333  19   0.333   0   0.667 0     0    
#> 5 RIX          1        1 0.4    13   0.4     0.2 0.2   0.2   0    
#> 6 RIX          1        2 0.4    17.2 0.2     0   0.4   0.2   0.2  
#> 7 RIX          2        1 0.4    13   0.4     0.2 0.2   0.2   0    
#> 8 RIX          2        2 0.429  16.4 0.143   0   0.286 0.286 0.286
```